# Adding Socket IO room functionality causes messages not to send

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, cors

I'm trying to implement the room feature from socket.io into my project however when I try implementing this line of code the messages don't show up anymore.

```
app.use(cors()); //allows data to be transfered between the client and server

const socketIO = require("socket.io")(http, {
  cors: {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
 },
});


  socket.on("message", (data) => {
  // socketIO.emit("messageResponse", data); previous line of code broadcasts messages to everyone
  socket.to(data.room).emit("messageResponse", data); //This line of code only broadcasts messages to users in the same room.
  console.log(data);
  });
```

Here is the "messageResponse" event and the handlesubmit function that sends all of the information to the backend of the website.

```
 const handleSendMessage = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (message.trim()) {
     socket.emit("message", {
        room: room,
        text: message,
        name: currentUser.displayName,
        id: `${socket.id}${Math.random()}`,
        socketID: socket.id,
     });
  }
     setMessage("");
 };

   useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("messageResponse", (data) => setMessages([...messages, data]));
  }, [socket, messages]);
```

The room variable is provided by the users' input

```
const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
   const [room, setRoom] = useContext(RoomContext);
   const navigate = useNavigate();

      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reload
         var roomInfo = e.target[0].value;
      
         setRoom(roomInfo);
         console.log(room);
         socket.emit("joinRoom", room);
      
      //sends the username and socket ID to the Node.js server
      socket.emit("newUser", { currentUser, socketID: socket.id });

      navigate("/live_chat");
   };
```

I created RoomContext so that the room variable could be used throughout the whole program.

Any feedback would be appreciated. If you need me to show you more lines of code or explain a few things just let me know.

Comment: Where are you getting the `room` variable on the client?